# Data that are not key-value pairs in TInifile

Tags: delphi, tinifile

I use Delphi and want to use an Inifile containing following data:

```
[physicians]
Amy
Bart
Chloe
Dean
Evy
Frank
```

I thought TInifile's ReadSectionValues would handle this, but it appears all lines which are not key-value pairs are ignored.
I would like to avoid adding dummy keys, like

```
[physicians]
dr_01 = Amy
dr_02 = Bart
dr_03 = Chloe
dr_04 = Dean
dr_05 = Evy
dr_06 = Frank
```

(Note that ReadSectionValues returns key-value pairs, not just the values, as the method's name suggests.)
Anyway, does TInifile have a method which can handle data without keys?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can still have sections with no key-value pairs when working with `TMemInifile`. In that case these items are stored as keys. To retrieve the items of such a section use `ReadSection`.

Comment: Thanks. I find it odd though that the ReadSection behaviour differs between TInifile and TMemInifile

Comment: It might be because TIniFile is based on a highly outdated Windows API which most likely is not going to change. IMHO it is a good move to decouple the behavior of TMemInifile from TIniFile to gain some advantage. Personally I probably stopped using TInifile in favor of TMemInifile decades ago.